# How to make a number picker that is same as color picker

Tags: javascript, reactjs, colors, slider

As you see when you search "color picker"  in google there is something like this:

[image]

I would like to do this in number range example 1-1000 because I will implement a price range

I'd also like to do this in react

Comment: Do you have a starting point you've worked on?  There are a lot of very different ways to go about doing this, and random attempts might not fit your use case.  As [@craws](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9254064/craws) mentioned, you might want to look at [react-range](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-range)